# React average a total of multiple values from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some troubles to do an average, so this is one of my reviews array

```
"reviews": [
        {
            "_id": "id",
            "review_text": "TEXT",
            "review_graphics": 8,
            "review_story": 10,
            "review_animation": 8,
            "review_writing": 10,
            "date": "2020-10-16T16:30:07.385Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "id",
            "review_text": "reviewPostText",
            "review_graphics": 5,
            "review_story": 10,
            "review_animation": 8,
            "review_writing": 7,
            "date": "2020-10-17T01:51:26.272Z"
            },
    ],
```

To get the average rating in a review I did basic maths in a .map

```
(review.review_graphics + 
 review.review_writing + 
 review.review_story + 
 review.review_animation) / 4
```

But I'd like to do this on every review and then get the total average of my review arrays.

Hope I'm clear, don't hesitate to ask me more infos

EDIT: better render for reviews json

Comment: What is the shape of each `review` entity? You say this "this is one of your review arrays", can you clarify on that?

Comment: If all review arrays are of this kind, your solution will work

Comment: It is a json data so review is an objet
@fesieg i did map to render the average of those values on each review but i can't pull off the total reviews average :/

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to do it by an other way.
In my form to post a review I do the average of the ratings that I put in the review model (I am using nodeJs/MongoDB)
Now my review object look like this :

```
{
    "_id": "id",
    "review_text": "TEXT",
    "review_graphics": 8,
    "review_story": 10,
    "review_animation": 8,
    "review_writing": 10,
    "review_rate": 9,
    "date": "2020-10-16T16:30:07.385Z"
},
```

So in the frontend component here is what I did:

```
 const scores = reviews.map((review)=>review.review_rate);
 const average = scores.reduce((totalRates, score) => totalRates + score, 0);
 const averageTotal = parseFloat((average / reviews.length).toFixed(2));
```